# Applications of Biology in Mathematics

Tags: applications, biology

I know that mathematics has applications in Biology, and in fact in everywhere, I am curious to know is it happened that a Biological concept comes to help math? I don't mean Biological names be chosen for a mathematical concept like Amoeba! I mean we get an idea to solve or do something or the math question be solved by a Biological method.

Comment: Maybe neural networks, which were loosely inspired by the brain.  Another example might be evolutionary algorithms.

Comment: Evolutionary algorithms would maybe be considered an application to math (or computer science).

Comment: There have been experiments using DNA strands to solve computational problems such as the "Travelling Salesman" (Hamilton path) problem.The idea is that if enough strands are allowed to mix together and link up, then some of the linkages will have the right mass to represent solutions to the problem .They can be separated from the rest by centrifuge. The goal is to solve computationally complex problems by brute force trial-and-error  using molecular collisions as the trials. I dk how far this has gone except that it worked in a very simple test case.

Comment: @user254665 is it a kind of randomized algorithm?

Comment: @littleO May you give me an easy link, references for those two things you mentioned?

Comment: I don't think I can give you better recommendations than what you'd find just by googling.  Andrew Ng's [tutorial](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/MultiLayerNeuralNetworks/) on neural networks might be pretty good.

Comment: @H.W.  I only recall that there was a Scientific American article many years ago. DNA strands represented edges of a graph. They could link end to end only with strands representing edges with a common end point, at the end representing that point.A large number of strands mixed together would form links by random collision.So a large number of different paths were randomly created.The test graph had only 7 nodes.The strand were of approximately equal weight ,A 3-way link at one end was chemically impossible so a  path  with weight approx. 7W would represent a Hamilton circuit.

Comment: You can find an example here where [Argentine ants solve the Towers of Hanoi](https://jeb.biologists.org/content/214/1/50).

Answer (score 2):

As I know there are methods in coding theory that are using Genetic Algorithm which has taken a pattern from actions between genes such as mutation, recombination and resamplaing. I will find a reference and will put it here for you.

You can look at my answer at this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473073/an-easy-reference-for-genetic-algorithm).