# An easy reference for genetic algorithm

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, coding-theory, biology

My field is Coding Theory and my background is Algebraic, there are many applications of Genetic Algorithm in Coding Theory, I would to know the easiest and the most elementary and introductory note about "Genetic Algorithm in Coding Theory", also is this algorithm using in Crypto too?

Answer (score 5):

1- A Genetic Algorithm for Solving Scheduling Problem, Habibeh Nazif, The Journal of Mathematics and Computer Science Vol .5 No.2 (2012) 91-9

2- Mathematical Analysis of Evolutionary Algorithms for Optimization, Heinz Muhlenbein, Thilo Mahnig

3- Between theory and practice: guidelines for an optimization scheme with genetic algorithms - Part I: single-objective continuous global optimization, Loris Serafino, arXiv